# Understanding transformer secondary winding

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, ac

I purchased a step down transformer from a junk yard. I tested the transformer and it works but I am confused as to the secondary winding.

The primary side has these markings
G 0V 100V

The secondary has these markings
37V 18V 0V 6V 0V

On the secondary the markings
37V 18V 0V are all connected.

The 6V and 0V on the right hand side are connected as well.

When I connect the transformer and try to take readings from the secondary, I get mostly 6-8V between any two points on the secondary.

Visual

```
      Primary
    G 0V 110V
------------------
------------------
     Secondary
 37V 18V 0V [space] 6V 0V
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on with this transformer?

Comment: Weird. A photo would be helpful. What do you mean by "try to take readings from the secondary, ... between any two points on the secondary"? According to what you describe, there are only two "points", one to the left of the [space] and the other to the right of it - as all contacts on either side are "connected" (shorted, isn't it?). So then there cannot be any voltage e.g. between the 37V and the 18V pin. Or do you mean something else by "connected"?